# Not able to create extesnion in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

When I am trying to create extension I am getting below mentioned error.

ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/adminpack": No such file or directory.

Thanks and Regards,
Mohit Dubey

Answer (score 0):

check with command

```
Select * from pg_available_extensions
```

if you not found adminpack install `postgresql-contrib`

Comment: try reinstall  postgresql-contrib

Comment: tried that too..still facing the issue..I guess I have twp postgres database installed into my system..Please can u tell me how to check that

Comment: which way you use to install postgres, do you restart service after reinstall ?

Comment: I dont remember exactly how I installed, Its been a long time back. But i can restart directly my service I have to do to pg_ctl -D /var/lib/pgsql/data2 restart from root. I cant restart using systemctl restart postgresql.service.

Comment: try run ps auxwww | grep postgres for file which postgres is running then, check folder extension in this folder. Or check with command sudo find / -name postgresql.conf

Answer (score 0):

Actually issue was that my *.so files were in /usr/pgsql-9.3/lib and in pg_config file /usr/lib64/pgsql path was given so I just copied all files from /usr/pgsql-9.3/lib to /usr/lib64/pgsql.

Issue is resolved.

Thanks everyone for your support.